# DocuSign C# SDK setting prefilled fields

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am attempting to set pre-filled fields before sending an email but it doesn't seem to be working. I have two such text fields with Data Labels `fee` and `otherFee`.

[image: fee]

[image: otherFee]

When attempting to send, the program throws the following error:
`{"errorCode":"REQUIRED_TAB_INCOMPLETE","message":"A Required field is incomplete. TabId: 0dfdf411-cafa-441e-b6e4-ef617e12de92"}`
`TabId` here changes with each call. I know it must be associated with my pre-filled fields because when I remove them, or remove the `Mandatory` attribute, via the template tool on the website the email is sent without issue. Not sure why I am getting this unique identifier rather than the Data Label they are actually set to.

My code:

```
            //prepare client
            var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            
            //Make the envelope
            TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole
            {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name =  signerName,
                RoleName = "merchant",
            };
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                TemplateId = templateId,
                TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer1 },
                Status = "created"
            };
            EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);

            //set fields
            Text fee = new Text {TabLabel = "fee", Value = "$0.50"};
            Text otherFee = new Text {TabLabel = "otherFee", Value = "$1.77"};
            PrefillTabs prefillTabs = new PrefillTabs {TextTabs = new List<Text> {fee, otherFee}};
            Tabs tabs = new Tabs {PrefillTabs = prefillTabs};
            var res = envelopesApi.CreateDocumentTabs(accountId, result.EnvelopeId, "1", tabs);
            
            //update and send
            Envelope envInfo = new Envelope();
            envInfo.Status = "sent";
            envelopesApi.Update(accountId, result.EnvelopeId, envInfo);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use prefill tabs, here is a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Prefill%20tabs).

**Your problem** is that you're trying to set the pre-fill tabs for a template. That is not supported. Instead, use regular tabs and mark them as read only. The [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com) has many template code examples you can try live.

As noted above, you cannot set prefill tabs for documents that are in a server template. See the [templates post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/use-template-luke)

Prefill tabs are more meant for humans using the DocuSign web app to **send** the envelope (transaction). Your API integration app can use regular tabs in read-only mode.

Here are JSON and C# examples for prefill tabs from the API Request Builder.

```
  "envelopeDefinition": {
    "emailSubject": "Please sign the attached document",
    "status": "sent",
    "documents": [
      {
        "filename": "anchorfields.pdf",
        "name": "Example document",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "prefillTabs": {
            "textTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "bold": "true",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "BrightBlue",
                "fontSize": "Size14",
                "value": "This field and the following are all \"prefill\" fields: "
              },
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "30",
                "bold": "true",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "Black",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "value": "Checkbox:"
              },
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "90",
                "anchorYOffset": "30",
                "bold": "true",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "Black",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "value": "Radio button:"
              },
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "0",
                "anchorYOffset": "60",
                "bold": "true",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "Black",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "value": "Sender name:"
              },
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "190",
                "anchorYOffset": "60",
                "bold": "true",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "Black",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "value": "Sender company:"
              }
            ],
            "checkboxTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "70",
                "anchorYOffset": "30",
                "fontSize": "Size14",
                "selected": "true"
              }
            ],
            "radioGroupTabs": [
              {
                "radios": [
                  {
                    "anchorString": "/field1/",
                    "anchorXOffset": "185",
                    "anchorYOffset": "30",
                    "selected": "true",
                    "fontSize": "Size14"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "senderNameTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "90",
                "anchorYOffset": "58",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "DarkGreen",
                "fontSize": "Size12"
              }
            ],
            "senderCompanyTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/field1/ ",
                "anchorXOffset": "310",
                "anchorYOffset": "58",
                "font": "Garamond",
                "fontColor": "DarkGreen",
                "fontSize": "Size12"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
        {
          "email": "signer_email@example.com",
          "name": "Signer's name",
          "recipientId": "1",
          "clientUserId": "1000",
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

### C#

```
        static string SendDocuSignEnvelope()
        {
            SignHere signHereTab1 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/sig1/",  
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",  
                AnchorXOffset = "20" 
            };
            List<SignHere> signHereTabs1 = new List<SignHere> {signHereTab1};
            Tabs tabs1 = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = signHereTabs1 
            };
            Signer signer1 = new Signer
            {
                ClientUserId = "1000",  
                Email = "signer_email@example.com",  
                Name = "Signer's name",  
                RecipientId = "1",  
                Tabs = tabs1 
            };
            List<Signer> signers1 = new List<Signer> {signer1};
            Recipients recipients1 = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = signers1 
            };
            Text textTab1 = new Text
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                Bold = "true",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "BrightBlue",  
                FontSize = "Size14",  
                Value = "This field and the following are all ""prefill"" fields: " 
            };
            Text textTab2 = new Text
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "0",  
                AnchorYOffset = "30",  
                Bold = "true",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "Black",  
                FontSize = "Size12",  
                Value = "Checkbox:" 
            };
            Text textTab3 = new Text
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "90",  
                AnchorYOffset = "30",  
                Bold = "true",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "Black",  
                FontSize = "Size12",  
                Value = "Radio button:" 
            };
            Text textTab4 = new Text
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "0",  
                AnchorYOffset = "60",  
                Bold = "true",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "Black",  
                FontSize = "Size12",  
                Value = "Sender name:" 
            };
            Text textTab5 = new Text
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "190",  
                AnchorYOffset = "60",  
                Bold = "true",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "Black",  
                FontSize = "Size12",  
                Value = "Sender company:" 
            };
            List<Text> textTabs1 = new List<Text> {textTab1, textTab2, textTab3, textTab4, textTab5};
            Checkbox checkboxTab1 = new Checkbox
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "70",  
                AnchorYOffset = "30",  
                FontSize = "Size14",  
                Selected = "true" 
            };
            List<Checkbox> checkboxTabs1 = new List<Checkbox> {checkboxTab1};
            Radio radio1 = new Radio
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/",  
                AnchorXOffset = "185",  
                AnchorYOffset = "30",  
                FontSize = "Size14",  
                Selected = "true" 
            };
            List<Radio> radios1 = new List<Radio> {radio1};
            RadioGroup radioGroupTab1 = new RadioGroup
            {
                Radios = radios1 
            };
            List<RadioGroup> radioGroupTabs1 = new List<RadioGroup> {radioGroupTab1};
            SenderName senderNameTab1 = new SenderName
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "90",  
                AnchorYOffset = "58",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "DarkGreen",  
                FontSize = "Size12" 
            };
            List<SenderName> senderNameTabs1 = new List<SenderName> {senderNameTab1};
            SenderCompany senderCompanyTab1 = new SenderCompany
            {
                AnchorString = "/field1/ ",  
                AnchorXOffset = "310",  
                AnchorYOffset = "58",  
                Font = "Garamond",  
                FontColor = "DarkGreen",  
                FontSize = "Size12" 
            };
            List<SenderCompany> senderCompanyTabs1 = new List<SenderCompany> {senderCompanyTab1};
            PrefillTabs prefillTabs1 = new PrefillTabs
            {
                CheckboxTabs = checkboxTabs1,  
                RadioGroupTabs = radioGroupTabs1,  
                SenderCompanyTabs = senderCompanyTabs1,  
                SenderNameTabs = senderNameTabs1,  
                TextTabs = textTabs1 
            };
            Tabs tabs2 = new Tabs
            {
                PrefillTabs = prefillTabs1 
            };
            Document document1 = new Document
            {
                DocumentId = "1",  
                FileExtension = "pdf",  
                DocumentBase64 = ReadContent("anchorfields.pdf"),  // filename is anchorfields.pdf
                Name = "Example document",  
                Tabs = tabs2 
            };
            List<Document> documents1 = new List<Document> {document1};
            EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
            {
                Documents = documents1,  
                EmailSubject = "Please sign the attached document",  
                Recipients = recipients1,  
                Status = "sent" 
            };

            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            try
            {
                EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
                Console.WriteLine($"Envelope status: {results.Status}. Envelope ID: {results.EnvelopeId}");
                return results.EnvelopeId;
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception while creating envelope!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Code: {e.ErrorCode}\nContent: {e.ErrorContent}");
                //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: @LarryK The link to the API request builder was helpful, I couldn't understand why I wasn't able to pre-fill the pre-fill fields via the API. Also identifying the tabs by tab label and not tab id was confusing, but have it working now I think